# Python: draw multiple positive/negative Bar Charts by conditions

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

This is my first time drawing bar charts in python.

My df op:

```
      key descript  score
0  noodles    taste      5
1  noodles    color     -2
2  noodles   health      3
3   apple    color      7
4   apple    hard      9
```

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
op['positive'] = op['score'] > 0
op['score'].plot(kind='barh', color=op.positive.map({True: 'r', False: 'k'}), use_index=True)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('sample1.png')
```

Output:

[image: Bar Chart]

But this is not what I expected. I would like to draw two charts by different keys in this case with index and maybe use different colors like below:

[image: expected Bar Chart]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Typo in data?  "noodels" vs "noodles"?

Comment: @ScottBoston yeah, it's a typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,op.key.nunique(), figsize=(15,5), sharex=True)
i = 0

#Fix some data issues/typos
op['key']=op.key.str.replace('noodels','noodles')

for n, g in op.assign(positive=op['score'] >= 0).groupby('key'):
    g.plot.barh(y='score', x='descript', ax=ax[i], color=g['positive'].map({True:'red',False:'blue'}), legend=False)\
    .set_xlabel(n)
    ax[i].set_ylabel('Score')
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    i += 1
```

Output:

[image]

#### Update added moving of labels for yaxis -  Thanks to this [SO solution by @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54008196/6361531)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,op.key.nunique(), figsize=(15,5), sharex=True)
i = 0

#Fix some data issues/typos
op['key']=op.key.str.replace('noodels','noodles')

for n, g in op.assign(positive=op['score'] >= 0).groupby('key'):
    g.plot.barh(y='score', x='descript', ax=ax[i], color=g['positive'].map({True:'red',False:'blue'}), legend=False)\
    .set_xlabel(n)
    ax[i].set_ylabel('Score')
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax[i].spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    plt.setp(ax[i].get_yticklabels(), transform=ax[i].get_yaxis_transform())
    i += 1
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try to find a way to move those yaxis tick lables over so that you don't have 'Score' and 'color' in the bar.  I'll take another look at this tomorrow.  Maybe one of the matplotlib wizards here can modify and move that text over.

Comment: It's very neat! Thank you :) It's not necessary to have yaxis tick lables, so I just hide it. I have one question, when I tried to draw the bar charts, I actually have more than 100 unique keys. I change subplots from (1,op.key.nunique()) to (op.key.nunique(),1) and change the figsize but the charts is pretty messy since they are too small and stick together. How do I solve this? I just want every picture as big as yours.

Comment: @cherrytree1 You are going to have to adjust the size of your figure to fit 100 images vertically.  Your fig size is the total size of the chart which includes all 100 of your subplots.  I you try figsize=(15, 500) at the end use `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. When I tried the code today, not sure why it cannot display the color properly. It shows all red when I tried it today.

Comment: Howdy, Cherry.  I not sure what your problem is but here is a working example.   https://repl.it/@scottboston/SOCharting2Colors

Comment: when I ran your code on my jupyter, the output of the plot has only red color, but there's one negative score in the dataframe. I just cannot print the blue one.

Comment: Upgrade matplotlib, and pandas