# How to move tick labels off left spine

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, how do I move the y tick labels to the far left side of the charting areas when I have moved the left spine?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = range(-10,5)
y = [i**2 for i in X]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,8))
plt.plot(X, y)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
```

Outputs:

[image]

However, I would like to get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the transformation of the y-ticklabels back to the original y-axis transform would give you the desired ticks on the left side of the axes.

```
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
```

[image]

Complete code for reproducibility

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = range(-10,5)
y = [i**2 for i in X]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,8))
plt.plot(X, y)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')

plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())

plt.show()
```

Comment: @Bazingaa The y position of the label should be determined by the data; so it is set at draw time, i.e. after you have made your changes.

Comment: Thanks, IOBE!  That is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I see. Thanks for the response.It would have been convenient though if there was a direct option something like `tick.label.set_xposition(-10)`

Comment: @Bazingaa I think this would create too much overhead in the code, given that a ylabel would need a set_xposition while am x-label would need a set_yposition.

Comment: Yeah you are right. While iterating over the ticks, it would also have to differentiate and throw error if yposition is used for ytick mistakenly and xposition is used for xtick

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the `set_position` attribute of your tick labels by iterating over them. Here you have to pass the (xy) value to be set as the new location of your tickl-labels. We know the x-position is -10. What I found is that it does not matter what y-position you specify, the ticks are offset by the value of `x` which kind of makes sense too because the tick labels have to correspond to the ticks on the y-axis. However, one can't leave the y-value empty. So specifying `(-10)` won't work and `(-10, 0)`, `(-10, -100)` or `(-10, 1000)` have no effect on the y-position of the ticks. The reason is as 
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest clarified: The y position of the label will be determined by the y-values of your data and is set at draw time after applying the changes.

```
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    print (tick.label.set_position((-10, 0)))
```

[image]