# Changing the colors for positive/negative values of a Matplotlib Bar Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am looking to change the colors of my bar graph based on if there are any negative values. I want positive values to be crimson and negative values to be deepskyblue. I can't seem to find the best method of accomplishing this.

What my figure looks like before I tried making changes: [Link to figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlSXj.png)

Below are segments of my code, with the last four lines being the problem (TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int':

```
    filename='2015_tAnoms.csv'

    lat = []
    tAnom = []
    with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
      points = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      next(points)
      for row in points:
        lat.append(int(row[0]))
        tAnom.append(Decimal(row[1]))


    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    import numpy as np
   
    figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.grid(color='lightgray', alpha=0.6, which='major', axis='y', linestyle='-')
    axes.set_facecolor((0,0,0))
    axes.set_xlim([-90,90])
    axes.set_ylim([-1,3])

    lat = np.array(lat)
    tAnom = np.array(tAnom)

    posValues = tAnom >= 0
    negValues = tAnom < 0

    plt.bar(lat[posValues],tAnom[posValues],color='crimson')
    plt.bar(lat[negValues],tAnom[negValues],color='deepskyblue')
```

[Image with correct coloring, but squished data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90tqi.png)

Comment: for `posValues = tAnom >= 0` to work, `tAnom` needs to be a numpy array. So, `tAnom = np.array(tAnom)`. Also `lat` needs to be a numpy array.  Note that if you use pandas' `pd.read_csv` many of this type of conversions happen automatically.

Comment: @JohanC that doesn't seem to work. I get a TypeError with my plt.bar lines saying that numpy.ndarray object is not callable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54000828/6361531

Comment: You also need square brackets in `plt.bar(lat[posValues],tAnom[posValues])`

Comment: Adding the square brackets worked, but the data got squished. See above link to image.

Comment: my latitude points were turned into my temperature anomaly (tAnom) points with the numpy array.